# NotesCalendarEntry with recurring event

Tags: xpages, ssjs

Hello I need to solve my old question [XPages search calendar range datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137867/xpages-ssjs-noteviewentry-with-multivalue-bug-or-not)
So I have rewrite my code for use NotesCalendar class and now this code return correctly the events (include the recurring/repeat event)

```
var startDateTime:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(new Date(2016,0,1));
var endDateTime:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(new Date(2016,1,1));
var cal:NotesCalendar = session.getCalendar(mailDB);
cal.readRange(startDateTime,endDateTime) //work correctly and return VCAL
```

but I need to read every Calendar Entries for create my JSON object so I have add this code:

```
var vect:java.util.Vector=cal.getEntries(startDateTime,endDateTime)
 for(j=0;j<vect.size();j++){
       var cale:NotesCalendarEntry = vect.elementAt(j);
        cale.read(); //this return NULL in recurring Event and work in other case   
       cale.recycle();
    }
```

This is my VCAL generate from ***cal.readRange(startDateTime,endDateTime)***

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160131T080000Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
RECURRENCE-ID:20160131T080000Z
DTSTAMP:20160203T084615Z
CLASS:PRIVATE
SUMMARY:test repeat event
UID:134A501D66B80411C1257E520058802B-Lotus_Notes_Generated
X-LOTUS-SUMMARYDATAONLY:TRUE
X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE:4
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT1H
DESCRIPTION:test repeat event
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160131T090000Z
DTEND:20160131T100000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTAMP:20160203T084615Z
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PRIVATE
SUMMARY:private test public appointment
UID:4C5E7D5116C19E7EC1257F4E00301400-Lotus_Notes_Generated
X-LOTUS-SUMMARYDATAONLY:TRUE
X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE:0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160201T070000Z
DTEND:20160201T080000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTAMP:20160203T084615Z
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
SUMMARY:public test -appointment
UID:802CB03D0FE29EC7C1257F4C005B9344-Lotus_Notes_Generated
X-LOTUS-SUMMARYDATAONLY:TRUE
X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

If I need to read every recurring events, I think that I need to use the function ***cale.read("20160131T080000Z")*** passing the RECURRENCE-ID.

But how can I in NotesCalendarEntry get this parameter my FOR statment?

Thank a lot

P.S. I can use Ical4j Java library I know. is this only solution?

Comment: The calendar rest service source code is actually on Github/OpenNTF - did you check how they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have solve my problem.
I have found a JavaScript library that convert VCAL into JSON object.
I have convert this JavaScript client library in SSJS code and voila!
Now work perfect and in simple mode!